# How to spawn seeds of NumPy SeedSequence during Parallel Random Number Generation?

Tags: python, numpy, random-seed, concurrent.futures

NumPy's documentation on [Parallel Random Number Generation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/parallel.html?highlight=seedsequence) shows how to use [SeedSequence](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/parallel.html?highlight=seedsequence#seedsequence-spawning) to spawn grandchildren seeds (see below).

> ```
> from numpy.random import SeedSequence, default_rng
>
> ss = SeedSequence(12345)
>
> # Spawn off 10 child SeedSequences to pass to child processes.
> child_seeds = ss.spawn(10)
> streams = [default_rng(s) for s in child_seeds]
> ```
>
> Child SeedSequence objects can also spawn to make grandchildren, and
> so on. Each SeedSequence has its position in the tree of spawned
> SeedSequence objects mixed in with the user-provided seed to generate
> independent (with very high probability) streams.
>
> ```
> grandchildren = child_seeds[0].spawn(4)
> grand_streams = [default_rng(s) for s in grandchildren]
> ```

**My question:**

To create the next generation of seeds, should I use:

```
 great_grandchildren = grandchildren[0].spawn(4)
 great_grand_streams = [default_rng(s) for s in great_grandchildren]
```

or should it alway reference `child_seeds[0]`:

```
great_grandchildren = child_seeds[0].spawn(4)
great_grand_streams = [default_rng(s) for s in great_grandchildren]
```

The context of my question concerns implementing the seeds and a function comprising of a `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` object that uses the seeds for each process in a while-loop scenario which can be "endless". I would like to know if the below is the correct way to spawn seeds from a `SeedSequence` assuming I had already consumed the `grandchildren` and `grand_streams` terms mentioned in NumPy's example. For example:

```
 from numpy.random import SeedSequence, default_rng
 
 ss = SeedSequence(12345)
 
 # Spawn off 10 child SeedSequences to pass to child processes.
 child_seeds = ss.spawn(10)
 streams = [default_rng(s) for s in child_seeds]
 
 run_func1( streams ) #child_seeds is consummed

 grandchildren = child_seeds[0].spawn(4)
 grand_streams = [default_rng(s) for s in grandchildren]

 while True:
     run_concurrent_futures_ProcessPoolExecutor_func( grand_streams )
     if condition_not_met:
         grandchildren = grandchildren[0].spawn(4) #Do I use grandchildren[0] or child_seeds[0] to ensure randomness?
         grand_streams = [default_rng(s) for s in grandchildren]
     else:
         break
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter.  You're building a tree, the structure of which is irrelevant, and the only different is whether your tree ends up with 3 levels or 2.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your answer. I have added a bit more information to my question. Could you review them and update your answer? Thanks.

Comment: You should not spawn a new SeedSequence every time through the loop.  Seeding the same PRNG repeatedly like that is pointless.

Comment: I meant spawning seeds from a SeedSequence and not to spawn a new SeedSequence. You had misunderstood my question. I don't understand your answer. Could you answer my question explicitly so as to help my understanding? Cheers.

Comment: Let me ask you a question: are you trying to generate the same random numbers every time you run your program?  That is, does it matter to you that the results are reproducible, or is it OK if they are random and different every time you run?

Comment: I want to start my program with a known seed and assign different seeds to each process in each while-loop. In the context of using Python's `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` object, the same seeds will be passed into each process`. I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: Right, so you only need to `spawn()` one SeedSequence per process.  You do not need to `spawn()` again within a single process unless it launches new child processes.

Comment: Yes. Hence my question on how to spawn. Do I spawn from `child_seeds[0]` or `grandchildren[0]`?

Comment: It does not matter.

Comment: Why does it not matter? I don't understand. If I reused `child_seeds[0]` in the while-loop, would I not get the same seed pattern as before? I was thinking it mattered, i.e `great_grandchildren` should be spawn from `grandchildren`. Spawning the next generation to grandchildren was not mentioned in the documentation hence question.

Comment: I noticed NumPy's example wrote `grandchildren = child_seeds[0].spawn(4)` and not `grandchildren = ss.spawn(4)` or `grandchildren = ss[0].spawn(4)`. Hence the rationale for my thinking. Can you explain your opinion on why it does not matter if `child_seeds[0]` or `grandchildren[0]` is used?

Answer (score 0):

`spawn` is intended to create independent RNGs for parallel processes. However, you don't have a parallel process: it's sequential, since you're checking the condition each time. So it doesn't matter what you do.

Note that you can keep spawning new sequences from each sequence, so you could change your code to:

```
from numpy.random import SeedSequence, default_rng

ss = SeedSequence(12345)

# Spawn off 10 child SeedSequences to pass to child processes.
child_seeds = ss.spawn(10)
streams = [default_rng(s) for s in child_seeds]

run_func1( streams ) #  child_seeds is consumed

while condition_not_met:
    child_seeds = ss.spawn(4)
    streams = [child_seeds (s) for s in grandchildren]
    run_concurrent_futures_ProcessPoolExecutor_func(streams)
```

But, in fact, you also need to think about which function should be taking responsibility for deciding how many streams are needed.

```
from numpy.random import SeedSequence

ss = SeedSequence(12345)
run_func1(ss.spawn(1)[0]) #  creates as many child seeds as it needs

while condition_not_met:
    #  creates as many child seeds as it needs
    run_concurrent_futures_ProcessPoolExecutor_func(ss.spawn(1)[0])
```